# How can I upgrade Qt's WebView to use a newer WebKit version?

Tags: c++, qt, webkit

I need to have WebSocket support for Qt's WebView, but the current version Safari/533.3 supports the older deprecated version of WebSockets. Is there a way to upgrade QWebView to use newer WebKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading several developer blog posts believe I should just wait for newer releases as they seem to be constantly improving their products.